# Spring is overwriting my headers - why?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-headers

I am trying to enable caching in an http response using `Spring`.  Here is the code that I am using to create the response.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MessagesEndpoint {

    MessagesService messagesService = new MessagesService();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/messages/{messagesToken}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getMessages(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> messages = messagesService.getMessages();

        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.append("var initMessages = ");
        out.append(mapper.writeValueAsString(messages));
        out.close();

        response.setHeader("Pragma", "Public");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=31556926");

    }
}
```

Here are my headers from my chrome dev tools.

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: too long
Host:localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/donations/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
```

As you can see the cache is `no-cache`.  Why are these headers being overwritten?

Comment: Look if you have a filter or something similar for your request-response cycles.

Comment: This is Spring-MVC which uses a Dispatch Servlet and not the request-response cycle (I think).

Comment: Dude, seems that you don't even know about general web development at all. A web application server attends a HTTP request and generates a HTTP response, the web application will handle the work, note that Spring MVC (and almost any other Java web mvc application framework) will only help you to ease how to accomplish this work, nothing more. Again: check if you have a filter or interceptor in your project that is rewriting the headers of your response.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything about web development.  Thanks for the tip.